# Having a routing issue and can't fetch data after I deployed my PERN app to heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, routes

When i was using my local server for my app, my PERN app was working perfectly by showing the json data on http://localhost:4000/trips but now that I deployed to heroku there seems to be no path to keep the json data. The heroku domain is https://travelbuddy-planner.herokuapp.com and i thought that going to https://travelbuddy-planner.herokuapp.com/trips would show my PostgreSQL data just like localhost did but now it seems I have no API.

In the heroku logs it says my app is trying to fetch from just "/" and "//new" instead of "/trips" and "/trips/new".

Does anyone why this is happening?

Here's code from my server.js file showing how i define my routes:

```
// get all trips
app.get('/trips', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const getTrips = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM trip")
        res.json(getTrips.rows)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})

// get specific trip
app.get("/trips/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const { id } = req.params
        const trip = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM trip WHERE id = $1", [id])
        res.json(trip.rows)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
})

//create trip
app.post('/trips/new', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { location, date, hotel, flights, days, nights, activities, reservations } = req.body
        const newTrip = await pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO trip (location, date, hotel, flights, days, nights, activities, reservations) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING *", 
            [location, date, hotel, flights, days, nights, activities, reservations]
        )
        res.json(newTrip.rows[0])
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
```

Also here are the links to the repos:

https://github.com/JCollinJones25/travelbuddy_frontend
https://github.com/JCollinJones25/travelbuddy_backend

Comment: do you have 2 heroku projects - one to deploy frontend and another to deploy backend?
your link (i guess that is backend https://travelbuddy-planner.herokuapp.com) works fine - when i go `/trips` or `/trips/1` i see json output on my screen

Comment: Thanks for answering! Shortly after posting this the json data showed up on /trips! I couldn’t get the heroku app to pull from there but I ended up hosting the frontend on Netlify and that worked fine!